# Why no stack trace using WinDbg !heap -a -p with .Net NT service?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

I have a Windows NT service written in .Net 4.5 with an unmanaged memory leak.

I believe I've found the leaking allocation, but am not getting any stack trace whatsoever.  Here is what I'm seeing:
    0:022> !heap -s

```
******************************************************************
                                          NT HEAP STATS BELOW
******************************************************************
LFH Key                   : 0x057e4cff15073499
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
      Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR
                        (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length
------------------------------------------------------------------
000000d80a200000 00000002    8376   7964   8176    564   236     4
000000d80a070000 00008000      64      4     64      2     1     1
000000d80a470000 00001002     260     64     60      8     7     1
000000d80a420000 00001002    1280    104   1080     15    10     2
000000d80a870000 00001002      60      8     60      2     1     1
000000d80a940000 00041002      60      8     60      5     1     1
000000d823320000 00041002      60     16     60      5     1     1
000000d8238f0000 00001002    7416   3160   7216     52    54     4
000000d8241f0000 00001002     260     64     60      7     5     1
000000d825110000 00001002      60      8     60      5     1     1
000000d825280000 00001002      60     12     60      3     2     1
000000d824e60000 00001002      60      8     60      5     1     1
000000d825840000 00001002     260     44     60      9     7     1
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Next, the `000000d8238f0000` heap looks suspect:

```
0:022> !heap -stat -h 000000d8238f0000
heap @ 000000d8238f0000
group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
370 60f - 14d390  (58.11)
50 59e - 1c160  (4.90)
21a 46 - 931c  (1.60)
87c5 1 - 87c5  (1.48)
200 32 - 6400  (1.09)
298 26 - 6290  (1.07)
219 2c - 5c4c  (1.01)
278 22 - 53f0  (0.91)
1b7 30 - 5250  (0.90)
1e3 29 - 4d5b  (0.84)
1cd 28 - 4808  (0.79)
279 1b - 42c3  (0.73)
26a 1b - 412e  (0.71)
25b 1b - 3f99  (0.69)
1e9 21 - 3f09  (0.69)
344 13 - 3e0c  (0.68)
2e2 14 - 39a8  (0.63)
2b6 15 - 38ee  (0.62)
216 1b - 3852  (0.61)
213 1b - 3801  (0.61)
```

Next the allocations of size 370:

```
 0:022> !heap -flt s 370
_HEAP @ d80a200000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    000000d8237c96a0 0038 0000  [00]   000000d8237c96b0    00370 - (free)
    000000d8237c9a20 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8237c9a30    00370 - (free)
    000000d8237c9da0 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8237c9db0    00370 - (free)
    000000d8237ca120 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8237ca130    00370 - (free)
_HEAP @ d80a070000
_HEAP @ d80a470000
_HEAP @ d80a420000
_HEAP @ d80a870000
_HEAP @ d80a940000
_HEAP @ d823320000
_HEAP @ d8238f0000
    000000d8238f8a00 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8238f8a10    00370 - (busy)
    000000d8238f8f30 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8238f8f40    00370 - (busy)
    000000d8238fbc00 0038 0038  [00]   000000d8238fbc10    00370 - (busy)
```

Finally the stack trace of the allocation:

```
0:022> !heap -p -a 000000d8237c96b0
address 000000d8237c96b0 found in
_HEAP @ d80a200000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    000000d8237c96a0 0038 0000  [00]   000000d8237c96b0    00370 - (free)
```

Does anybody have any idea why there is no stack trace?  I've tried several allocations and none show a stack.  The behavior is the same with both a full dump and live debugging.

Also, same results with both SOS loaded and not loaded.

Comment: SOS is for .NET and not very helpful in case of unmanaged leaks. How did you enable the stack trace database and what size have you chosen for it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank you!  I had not enabled user stack trace.  Using gflag to enable ust and restarting the process worked.  I now have stack traces.

Comment: @ThomasWeller How can I accept this as the answer?

Comment: @mattman if you like you can post your steps as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinDbg help says

> -p Specifies that page heap information is being requested
>
> -a [...] Stack traces are included whenever available. [...]

so you're using the correct options. However, the point "whenever available" needs to be considered.

To get those stacks, use `gflags` and enable "Create user mode stack trace database" and define a size for it. 50 MB is quite ok, since it will only record the addresses and resolve the symbol names later (so it will not store a string with all the method names).

[image: GFlags enable stack trace database]

SOS is for .NET and not helpful in case of unmanaged leaks.